# How do I use the Japanese word 素直(Sunao) for upfront?

Tags: na-adjectives

I've been trying to find the Japanese word for upfront for a while now. And about two to three days ago, I got my answer. However, every time I try to translate it in a sentence, it says "docile" or "obedient." How do I use it for the aforementioned word?

Comment: Have you tried Jisho's examples? https://jisho.org/search/%E7%B4%A0%E7%9B%B4%20%23sentences

Comment: No sentences with upfront.

Comment: A quick glance at those and I don't see really any at the top that are "docile / obedient." They are all the "honest / frank / upfront" meaning.

Comment: My mistake. Stupid RomajiDesu. I guess that's how little I know about the language and how much of an idiot I made myself appear as. My apologies.

Comment: So, would "I was upfront" translate to "すなおわだった (sunaowadatta?)" My gut tells me the answer is " No."

Comment: If you mean for "wa" to be the topic marker, the correct way to write it is は, but it's not grammatical in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying to find the Japanese word for upfront for a while now.

"Sunao" doesn't really correspond closely to "upfront", maybe try something like 率直【そっちょく】 for that.

> However, every time I try to translate it in a sentence, it says "docile" or "obedient." How do I use it for the aforementioned word?

It sounds as if you're plugging things into Google translate and trying to get it to come up with something where sunao comes out approximately like that. If so, how about

> [素直に答えてください。](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E7%B4%A0%E7%9B%B4%E3%81%AB%E7%AD%94%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)

This is a common phrase which means something like "stop beating about the bush".

Comment: I was trying to use RomajiDesu's translator. But yes, that taught me a lesson. Thank you for your assistance. And to be honest, I'm researching the language with Yale University's textbooks.

Comment: Since *honest* and *frank* are [synonyms of upfront](https://www.lexico.com/definition/upfront), I think 素直 fits the meaning just fine when looking at some more [example sentences](https://www.lexico.com/definition/upfront).

Comment: "Doesn't really correspond closely"

Answer (score 0):

[**When I took synonyms for upfront,**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/up%20front) (though "in advance" sounds a little different to me),

> direct, open, frank, forthright, (etc)

came up.

So I think your "translation" into 率直｛そっちょく｝にaka素直｛すなお｝にseem to sound to fit with it.

Comment: The questioner didn't translate it as that, I did in my answer.